# Find using regex with altenatives

Tags: regex, shell, find

I try to use `find` to match several alternative file patterns represented by certain numbers in the middle, but it returns an empty list. My actual pattern has a fixed beginning and variable numbers in the middle.

Reproducible example. Create a list of files

```
touch a10a a24b b12c a45d
```

Select `a10a` and `a24b` from the list using the following regex resulting in empty output

```
find . -regex '.*/a(10|45).*'
```

I expect that the issue should be easy to solve but I could not find a solution and could not figure out it. What did I miss?

system: ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is right, but you need to type of the regex to use for `find`. Since you have alternate operator `|` here, you need to enable ERE (Extended Regular Expressions) support which you can do as below. The `-regextype` allows you to specify the regex flavor that you need for the requirement. Also the `/` part is optional if you have enabled a greedy match `.*`

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/a(10|45).*'
```

From my version of GNU findutils, you could see from the `man` page

> `-regextype type`
>
> Changes  the  regular  expression syntax understood by `-regex` and `-iregex` tests which occur later on the command line.  Currently-implemented types are `emacs` (this is the default), `posix-awk`, `posix-basic`, `posix-egrep` and `posix-extended`.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying `-regextype awk` instead:

```
find . -regextype awk -regex '.*/a(10|45).*'
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are using the wrong type of bracket. They should be square, not round.

*The correct command should be:*

```
find . -regex '.*/a[10|45].*'
```

Hope this helps!